# Extra White Space/White Background around Components because of Navigation React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

After making the screens, I connected them with stack navigation. But when I am implementing navigation there is an extra space around my screen components and my layout shifted a lot. I have tried every thing but could not able to resolve it.

Thanks in advance

[navigation.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck9nD.png) =>this is my navigation.js

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIivS.png)=>this is app.js with nothing inside <Navi..Contain..>.

[Mobile Screen referencing above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I7up.jpg) =>Screen in phone with nothing inside <Navi..Contain..>

[Home Screen Component without any Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8nZb.png)=>this is app.js with with HomeScreen in <Navi..Contain..>

[Mobile Screen with HomeScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYH38.jpg)=>Mobile screen with homeScreen Component

[Navigation Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YREi8.png)**==>Navigation inside <Navi..Contain..>**

[Mobile Screen referencing above point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcAwe.jpg)**==>Navigation inside <Navi..Contain..> Screen You can see the layout has been shifted and there is extra white space which i need to remove it**

Comment: Have you tried not using a top level SafeAreaView? Should be screen based not root level based

Comment: I have tried but didn't work. I even removed SafeAreaView but it didt make any change

Answer (score 0):

I don't what was going on but what I did was I created a mock screen and shifted my code one component by one. After shifting all of my code, it behaves in way that it supposed to behave.

Comment: I know it's tedius, but it would be useful if you could reproduce this procedure and track down exactly which component was giving you the issue and why. That would not only help you, it could help many others who come here with the same issue.

Comment: Sure I will do that...